# MS Excel : How do I add control box for activating custom views?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created some custom views in my excel document. Normally I use `view>custom views>select view` method to activate related view.  Is it possible to make this job by adding control buttons on excel sheet?

For example there will be a button for each custom view and when I click the button it will show me related view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by enabling the Developer tab in Excel Options, selecting Design Mode, and inserting a Button form control.

When you insert the button control, Excel should open the macro dialog with a macro name like Button1_Click. When you see that, click New on the macro dialog. This will open the event handler for the Button#_Click event in the Visual Basic editor. You'll need to add a line of code to the event handler, so that it looks like this...

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    ' this is a comment...
    ThisWorkbook.CustomViews("CustomViewName").Show
End Sub
```

Replace CustomViewName with the actual name of the view you want to show. When you leave design mode and click the button, it should show your custom view. Just add a button and repeat for each view.